# Iterate over an ember model query

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

```
this.store.findAll('game').then(function(results){
   // RUN SOME OPERATION ON THEM
})
```

I would like to know how I can play with the **results** variable. I understand I can do

```
results.get('firstObject') // returns the first object.
```

I'd like to know everything else I can do with it. Is there any api documentation for the **results** collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/finding-records/#toc_retrieving-multiple-records),

The below methods, will return the Promise, it will be resolved to Record or RecordArray.

`store.findAll()` returns a `DS.PromiseArray` that fulfills to a `DS.RecordArray`.
`store.findRecord` returns a promise that will be resolved with the `record`.
`store.query()` returns a `DS.PromiseArray` in the same way as findAll.

The below two are synchronus method, it will retrieve what is available in the store and returns record itself. it will not request the server to fetch data.

`store.peekAll` directly returns a `DS.RecordArray`.
`store.peekRecord` direclty returns record

> It's important to note that `DS.RecordArray` is not a JavaScript
>   array, it's an object that implements `Ember.Enumerable`. This is
>   important because, for example, if you want to retrieve records by
>   index, the [] notation will not work--you'll have to use
>   `objectAt(index)` instead.

From [Ember.Enumerable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html), most of the time I happened to use the following,
`forEach` to iterate
`map` to transform to new Array
`filterBy` `findBy` for filtering based on single property check
`toArray` converting to normal native array

Comment: Is this all true for store.query()? The Ember Guides only say it returns a "promise" which I'm not clear what that means.

Comment: yes its true for `store.query` too. I updated with more info. in the guide they mentioned like this `This method returns a DS.PromiseArray in the same way as findAll.`

Answer (score -3):

findAll will return a Promise which will resolve to a RecordArray. 
The RecordArray is an ArrayProxy.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

This is everything you need.

If you google "ember findall" you will find docs for "Ember.js - Models: Finding Records - Guides" as well.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/finding-records/