# Accessing data from recordArray in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Let us say i have a model X

```
  idOfX: DS.attr()
  shouldBeIncluded: DS.attr(),
  type: DS.attr(),
  valueOfX: DS.attr(
```

And I'm trying to fetch all elements of type x using [findAll](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll)/[peekAll](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekAll) methods of ember store.

After the store method resolves with data, I want to be able to filter data on `type` attribute or do some operations using `valueOfX` attribute.

What is the best way to access these values.

Note: Previously I was accessing `record` attribute of  `internalModel` object in recordArray. But with ember data 2.11.x record attribute is null until i explicitly fetch each record with getRecord method. And I don't know why/how that is happening.

Could anyone suggest share thoughts on it?

I'm using ember-cli@2.10.0, ember@2.10.0

Comment: Avoid attribute name `type` i guess it's reserved for ember-data. in one of the later release you might get error. to iterate refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41716142/5771666

Comment: I made up this model just for an example sake, let's assume `type` is changed to `isOfType`

Comment: ok. then  Ebrahim answer is applicable to your question. you can use any of the enumerable methods defined in Ember.ArrayProxy

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use internal model.

For accessing the model instances you need to do like :

```
this.get('store').findAll('x-model').then((dataList) => {
  //deal with dataList like an array
  dataList.forEach((item) => {
     //the item is the exact model instance and 
     //you can access to attributes like belo
     let type = item.get('type');  //for example
  });
});
```

for `peekAll` is the same

Comment: The `dataList` in this case will be of type `subclass of Ember.ArrayProxy`. I need to get the actual contents of each record to do the operations. So, `dataList` has `get` method calling it with `contents` argument will fetch contents array. Which is an array of internalModel for each record. And the problem comes back to where it started from.

Comment: @yuvrajzohan You can iterate over `dataList` and access to each element. No need to access to `content` directly.  I updated my answer to clarify

Comment: This seems to be working fine and as I needed. The documentation in ember data does not clearly specify data accessing. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is correct, but you can also just do this `dataList.toArray()` instead of `dataList.forEach(...)`, depending on the use case.

Comment: @alex I ended up using forEach. But is there any benefits leveraged with dataList.toArray() as compared to dataList.forEach(). As I have to iterate the dataList anyway either it's of array class or arrayProxy class.

Comment: @yuvrajzohan it's not better for this particular use case, but there are times when forEach isn't needed. I mentioned it for completeness so people don't use forEach just to reimplement toArray.

Comment: @AlexMA Yep. I did, indeed needed toArray in the same app in other part of the code for simplicity. Thanks