# How to map model data to a chart-friendly array in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, charts, ember-data

I have a model in a route that has data i'd like to chart using a chart plugin (ember-google-charts or ember-charts specifics do not matter to my issue)

in `routes/server.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      stats: this.store.query('stat', {filter: {serverId: params.server_id}})
      server: this.store.findRecord('server', params.server_id),
    })
  },
  setupController(controller, models) {
    controller.setProperties(models);
  }
 }
});
```

My issue where/how to make stats into a proper array (using timechecked and players attributes) in order to pass the data into a charting plugin in the template.

I've tried something similar to:

```
stats: this.store.query('stat', {filter: {serverId: params.server_id}}).then(items => {
    //modify items here

})
```

but i have a hard time figuring out how to manipulate the data and build a new array without throwing errors using a forEach (which exists on the ember Array class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can use `forEach` to iterate and return result you created. refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41716142/5771666) for work with ember model

```
stats: this.store.query('stat', { filter: { serverId: params.server_id } }).then(items => {
        //modify items here
        let result =[];
        items.forEach(function(element) {
          let value1 = element.get('propertyName');
          result.pushObject(value1);          
        }, this);
        return result;
    })
```

2. If you just want plain array then you can use [`toArray` method](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_toArray).

Comment: perfect - I was pretty close to this but i was missing the element.get('propertyName'). Cleared my confusion 100%